# how to delete one record from array of object in c++

Tags: c++

for eg

input name:jacob
input id:1234

input name:dani
input id:444

enter id to delete data :444
data deleted succesfully ;

after that display the remaining data

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
  class student{
   char name[20];
   int id;
   public:
    int search(int k);
    void adddata(){
     cout<<"input name :";
     cin>>name;
     cout<<"input id :";
     cin>>id;
    }
   void display(){
    cout<<name<<endl;
    cout<<id<<endl;
}
    
};

          }
    int main(){
        int d;
        student data[5];
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            data[i].adddata();
        }
        
        cout<<"enter id to delete data :";
        cin>>d;
        
        
        }
}
```

Comment: An array is not a good container for such purposes. Use std::list.

Answer (score 4):

> how to delete one record from array of object in c++

It isn't possible to erase element of an array. An array has a constant number of elements through its lifetime.

The C++ standard library provides an implementation of "resizable array" data structure. It's called `std::vector`. You can erase from it using the `erase` member function.

However, since you appear to be searching elements by arbitrary "id", an associative data structure would be more efficient for that use case, such as `std::unordered_set`.